# VueJS Select2 - Adding Option to Passed Option in On Initialising

Tags: vuejs2, jquery-select2

Hopefully I can explain this.

I have a Select2 Component as shown in the VueJS documentation.

I am using this drop down to give the user a list of for example cities. Now the list of cities have been set, but users are able to add other cities if the one they want is not in the list (the set data never is updated).

So for example lets say you have "City One", "City Two" and "City Three".

The user wants to have the value "City Four", so as tags is true they can type in "City Four" and select this value, it is set and the save is made and "City Four" is now sent to the database.

Next time the user comes back to this record the value "City Four" is retrieved from the database and should be displayed as the option in the drop down. However as the set cities options that are sent to Select2 do not contain the value "City Four" it is not shown.

I have a JSFiddle where I hope this is demonstrated:
https://jsfiddle.net/Morney/958wrbvd/1/

```
Vue.component('select2', {
    props: ['options', 'value'],
    template: '#select2-template',
    mounted: function () {
        var vm = this
        $(this.$el)
            .val(this.value)
            // init select2
            .select2({ data: this.options, tags: true, allowClear: true })
            .val(this.value)
            .trigger('change')
            // emit event on change.
            .on('change', function () {
                vm.$emit('input', this.value)
            })
    },
    watch: {
        value: function (value) {
            // update value
            $(this.$el).val(value).trigger('change');
        },
        options: function (options) {
            // update options
            $(this.$el).empty().select2({ data: options })
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        $(this.$el).off().select2('destroy')
    }
})

var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#demo-template',
    data: {
        selectedCity: 'City One',
        selectedCityTwo: 'City Four',
        cityOptions: [
            { id: 'City One', text: 'City One' },
            { id: 'City Two', text: 'City Two' },
            { id: 'City Three', text: 'City Three' }
        ]
    }
})
```

Does anyone know how I can work around this please so that the value can be displayed even when it is not in the list, but the user could still pick a value from the list if they needed to change it.

Hope this make sense, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a different list of options without changing the initial city list, then you must introduce a new list that will serve as the model for the other select.

To do this, you can use a computed method that will combine the initial list with the list of items retrieved from the database :

```
data: {
    cityOptions: [
      { id: 'City One', text: 'City One' },
      { id: 'City Two', text: 'City Two' },
      { id: 'City Three', text: 'City Three' }
    ],
    additionalCityOptions: [
        { id: 'City Four', text: 'City Four' }
    ]
}, 
computed: {
    cityOptionsDisplayed() {
        return [
        ...this.cityOptions, 
        ...this.additionalCityOptions
        ];
    }
}
```

Then use the new city options as a model for the select :

```
<select2 :options="cityOptionsDisplayed" v-model="selectedCityTwo">
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/958wrbvd/8/